# Serving static files in express in heroku app

Tags: node.js, express, routes, single-page-application, svelte

I have **two** svelte (SPA) applications - one for admin and one for the public, and I'm trying to serve both of them with one express server. 
when I run this code on my localhost it's works fine, but in heroku I'm getting 404 on the static files of the admin page (the client app is fine).

my project structure:

`server.js
client
      public
            build
                bundle
client
      public
            build
                bundle`

this is my html page that produces the invalid calls

```
<head>
    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/admin/global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/admin/build/bundle.css'>
    <script defer src='/admin/build/bundle.js'></script>
</head>
```

this is my express routeing:

```
app.get('/admin', utils.ensureToken, (req, res, next) => {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin/public')));
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('admin', 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client', 'public', 'index.html'));
});
app.use('/admin', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public')));
```

tried mixing the paths on express, but didn't seems to work. thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the project structure you have, you show files `client/build/bundle.{js,css}`, but in your express server, it's looking for `client/public/build/bundle.{js,css}` (`/build` folder should be in `/public` or you need to change the path in the `express.static()` call).

Comment: sorry, was wrong in the tree structure, I edited that - it's has a public/build..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it was the package.json that was the problem. 
forgot that the script "heroku-postbuild" needs to also run the "admin" npm start.